# Probability - 0.4% of women are colorbind and 8% of Men.

Tags: probability

0.4% of women are colorbind and 8% of Men. In a class theres 15 Men and 19 women. What are the odds that atleast 2 students are colorblind?

Comment: Please show your efforts on the question to avoid it being closed or heavily downvoted. See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question?r=SearchResults) to know how to ask a good question on this website. (Please take note that this website does **not** do your homework for you)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's "at least 2", we should find the probability of 0 and 1 students being colorblind and subtract that from 1.

I'll get you started for the 1 student being colorblind.

We can split this into two cases: 1 man colorblind or 1 woman colorblind.

**Case 1: 1 Man**

Since men have an $8\%$, or $0.08$ chance of being colorblind, and there are 15 men, one man will be colorblind and 14 will not. The chance of not being colorblind is $100\%-8\%=92\%=0.92$.

We can choose one man from the 15 men. This can be done in 15 ways.

Our probability now is $15 \cdot 0.08 \cdot (0.92)^{14} \approx 37.343\%.$

I feel that based on this info you can calculate the second case. After that, you can also calculate the 0 students being colorblind probability. Remember to subtract the sum of all the probabilities from 1, since we want to know the probability of 2 students *or more*, while we're doing *1 or less*.

-FruDe